# Logging on to a reporting server through hamachi

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, hamachi

I am trying to log on to a reporting service through Hamachi (A virtual private network client) as I want my program to access the report service from any computer which is most likely not going to be on the same network as my report server. I can log on to the report server using the server name no problem but when I try and use the Hamachi IP I get the credential request form but whatever I put it is rejected!

Any help would be appreciated as this is driving me mad!

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced problems where SSRS behaves differently when accessing by its FQDN and an IP address. It would help if you can turn on logging and see what the exact error number is.

One of the causes is to do with the host headers; SSRS checks to see if they match the local machine or not, and as the IP address you're giving doesn't match the loopback adapter or the local name, it denies the login.

This blog has a quick method or two to resolve that, and it will at least knock off one of the possibilities:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukaszp/archive/2008/07/18/reporting-services-http-401-unauthorized-host-headers-require-your-attention.aspx